# GIT re-merge files from dev to master

Tags: git, merge, clone, git-clone

My master GIT branch seams to have some errors thus I'd like to recheck, re-merge or possibly clone my dev branch over the master branch so the master branch would be a copy of dev.

How can I do that?
Thx.

Comment: When you say the master branch has errors, what do you mean? Git is *good* at preventing data loss, so what exactly has gone wrong? A little more information on exactly what the problem is would be helpful. Is `dev` descended from `master`? How different are they?

Comment: Hey, a friend made a push with --force and now master branch is 'Up-to-date' but files are not :). Strange.

Comment: So they pushed into a repo with a working copy?

Comment: Well no... and dont know what is ok and what is not. Dev branch has been merged into master and then pushed with conficts using --force :). Don't ask :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the problem is simply that your checked-out files don't match up with the branch, just use `git reset` normally:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

That should be all you need. However, if you still want to overwrite master with dev, read on.

---

If you want to overwrite your master branch with the contents of your dev branch, use `git reset` like so:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard dev
```

And then if you want to push this somewhere else:

```
$ git push origin master
```

Note that if your dev branch doesn't fast-forward from your master branch (which I'm guessing it won't, since you said that your master branch has some screwed up stuff in it), you'll need to add the `--force` flag to the push to overwrite it on a remote:

```
$ git push origin master --force
```

Note, however, that this can involve all of the normal caveats of rewriting history a la `git rebase` - if anyone else uses this remote, they'll need to deal with the equivalent of an upstream rebase.

---

To avoid this problem in the future, advise your friend that using `--force` is almost *never* necessary. If they're getting conflicts when they try to `git push`, they should `git pull` first, resolve the conflicts, and then `git push`.

Comment: Hum... Error: fatal: ambiguous argument 'dev': both revision and filename, Use '--' to separate filenames from revisions. Ehm... what should I do :)?

Comment: You could use `git log` to find out the commit ID of the head of `dev` and use `git reset --hard <id>`

Comment: Thanks also to @Cameron Skinner, I did it using git reset --hard {id} and then git merge dev, git push --force. Thx!

Comment: @xpepermint - in the future, you could have simply done `git reset --hard dev --`. Also, since you're already resetting to the head of `dev`, there's no need to `git merge` afterwards - just `git push`.

Answer (score 1):

From you comments it seems there are three possible cases:

1. The master index contains correct code and the working copy is broken.
2. The working copy is fine and the index is now broken.
3. Both are broken.

First, back everything up. Then:

In case 1, use `git reset --hard HEAD` to throw away the broken working copy.

In case 2, add and commit everything in the working copy.

In case 3, use `git reset --hard dev` to throw away both the index and the working copy. Alternatively, `git reset --hard SOME_COMMIT_ID_THAT_ISN'T_BROKEN`

In all three cases tell your friend to never use `--force` unless they really know what they're doing.

Also, it's probably best not to push into a non-bare repository (i.e. one with a working copy). I'd suggest you set up a bare repository somewhere that you both push and pull from rather than pushing directly into a repo that has a working copy. Use `git init --bare` to create a bare repo.

Did I mention back everything up? Good. Do it.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I have wanted to do this before myself and I never did. My best guess might be to try the below. *NOTE* I'm not sure how well this will work for you since I have not done it myself.

```
git checkout master

git pull origin dev

git commit -a -m "reverted to dev"
```

Doing it the above way will likely cause conflicts.

Comment: Hey, thx for your answer. It does't work. It works but does not overwrite my existing master branch. The problem is that a friend make a push with --force and now some data are not sync.

Comment: `git pull` is the equivalent of `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. Since `git merge` does not "overwrite" anything, it's not the right thing to do in this case.

Comment: @Amber your answer is best. I forgot about --hard branch I only ever do it on the current branch.